# internet android 7+

Tags: android, сеть, permissions, android-permissions

В разработке на андроид новичек. Сейчас пишу небольшую прогу, цель которой - связь в реальном времени между несколькими телефонами (через api вк). 
Сейчас узнал, что приложения, запущенные на андроид 7+, не видят интернет (хотя на устройстве связь есть). Прописаны permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

но ситуацию это не меняет - приложение интернета не видит. Может быть это из-за того, что люди ставили приложение из apk, не через маркет? Что нужно поменять (наверно, добавить в манифест?) для работы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советы ниже правильны и актуальны. Я же столкнулся с тем, что не мог получить данные, потому что запрашивал данные по https, а с android 7+ google выпилила поддержку ssl, и теперь надо их(libcrypto.so & libssl.so) докладывать руками в приложение. Надо быть внимательным - библиотеки, собранные под другую abi, вызовут креш. 

Инструкция по сборке библиотек: https://habr.com/company/intel/blog/271013/

Список возможных ABI:https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk

ABI:=all лучше не указывайте, а перечислите их вручную: all при невозможности сборки какой-либо одной платформы остановит сборку.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что начиная с `android 6+` необходимо запрашивать разрешения на что-либо в рантайме. Даже если ваш `targetSdkVersion` < 23, это все равно необходимо делать, так как пермишены можно отозвать в настройках смартфона.

Делается это так.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 1);
```

Более подробный пример

```
//Проверка версии SDK устройства
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                //динамическое получение прав на internet
                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permission is granted");

                    //делаете что-то с интернетом

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
                    //запрашиваем разрешение
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 1);
                }
            } else {
                //делаете что-то с интернетом
            }
```

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 1):

`<permission>` обычно используется при создании пользовательских разрешений (например, при создании приложения, к которому могут подключаться другие приложения, ограничение доступа является обязательным), а `<uses-permission>` используется, когда ваше приложение действительно нуждается в разрешении.

Добавьте и:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/> 
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Первый вопрос - что значит "не видит интернета"? Другие приложения видят? Технологически 7+ в этом отношении не сильно отличается от других версий, при пермишне INTERNET интернет работать должен даже без запроса в рантайме. Если интернет "не видят" и другие приложения, то проблема в телефоне - стоит дохлый прокси, или проблема с эмулятором - я недавно сталкивался с таким на windows, в таком случае надо через adb рестартнуть dns, тогда эмулятор получит доступ к internet.

Второй вариант - если другие приложения "видят интернет", тогда ошибка может быть в двух местах

1) В подключенной библиотеке - okHttp или чем там вы пользуетесь. Тогда надо либо дождаться фикса со стороны автора, либо продаунгрейдить версию до рабочей, либо как сказал W_bear пересобрать либу

2) Самый частый случай - проблема у вас в коде (проекте) - запрашиваете не тот url, не работает backend, запрашиваете как то не так. В  этом случае отлично помогает логгирование запросов, можно написать руками,либо воспользоваться сторонними логгерами, тот же okHttp предлагает OkHttpLoggingInterceptor, который возвращает всю информацию о запросе и ответе сервера в LogCat

Upd:

О, W_bear это вы :)) В любом случае запомните подход, пригодится в дальнейших проектах. Прошу прощения за невнимательность