# Почему приложение не спрашивает разрешения при установке

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Андроид приложение  при установке не запрашивает разрешения, указанные в манифесте. У меня там был сервис для оповещений. И он вообще не работает. В манифесте все прописано по всем канонам, но когда устанавливаю, пишет

> для этого приложения не требуются специальные разрешения.

несмотря на то, что там много `uses-permission`. Как можно сделать так, чтобы спрашивало при установке?

Comment: Гляньте тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/789046/internet-android-7/789056#789056

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Начиная с версии API `23` (Android 6.0), «[dangerous](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html)» разрешения нужно [запрашивать в рантайме](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Проверяем, есть ли нужные разрешения:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Разрешение не получено
}
```

Запрашиваем разрешения:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
```

Обрабатываем результат получения разрешений:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {

            // При отмене предоставления разрешений, этот массив пуст
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Разрешение получено

            } else {

                // Пользователь отказался предоставлять разрешение
            }
            return;
        }

        // Обрабатываем другие разрешения
    }
}
```