# Qt под android 7+

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, android-permissions

Всем доброго времени суток.
Занимаюсь разработкой qt под android и начал сталкиваться с проблемой отсутствия интернета на андроид 7 и выше в приложении, при том что интернет в телефоне есть.
Вот вопрос, который уже поднимал здесь, но его решение рассчитано на android studio, а не на qt:
[internet android 7+](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/789046/internet-android-7)
Как можно запросить права на интернет в рантайме(qt 5.10.1)? пытаюсь это сделать такой конструкцией, но результата нет:

```
#include "my_app.h"
#include <QApplication>
#ifdef ANDROID
#include <QtAndroid>
#endif
#include <QMessageBox>

bool checkPermission(const QString& perm)
{
#ifdef ANDROID
QtAndroid::PermissionResult r = QtAndroid::checkPermission(perm);
if(r == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied)
{
    QtAndroid::requestPermissionsSync( QStringList() << perm );
    r = QtAndroid::checkPermission(perm);
    if(r == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Ошибка", "получить разрешение не             удалось");
         return false;
}
}
#endif
return true;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

checkPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE");
checkPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE");
checkPermission("android.permission.INTERNET");

QApplication a(argc, argv);
MyApp w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: абалдеть, такое бывает (QT под android!). Чем же вам студия не угодила, что вы в QT это делаете?

Comment: Георгий, qt хороший инструмент, и удобен не только в плане написания кросс-платформенных приложений и ui. У него есть свои варианты реализации для большого количества разных задач в самых разных областях. А его документация(ИМХО) самая подробная. Попробуй и пойми, насколько это удобно.

Comment: Только что пересобрал на qt 5.11.1, убрал из манифеста права и попытался получить их только через эту конструкцию. Права на wifi не получил, права на состояние сети и тырнет вроде получить удалось, но связь все равно не появилась. Телефон был подключен к wifi. Если в манифесте права есть, то получение прав проходит, но связи все одно нет. Указывал минимальный сдк 16, и целевой сдк 16(думал, он подцепится за счет режима поддержки более старых вертий) - но не сработало. Народ, но ведь должно быть решение!

Comment: Сейчас наткнулся на такое решение. СЗОТ, временно оставлю его здесь, вечером напишу, как работает
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715452/calling-java-functions-in-qt-for-runtimepermissions/44735762

Comment: К сожалению, вызов java-кода с разрешениями результата не принес, хотя код вызывается, и нормально отрабатывает. Но тырнета в приложении нет по-прежнему. Появилась мысль, что это, возможно, из-за того, что запрашиваю данные по протоколу https, который может не поддерживаться по-умолчанию, как появится возможность - проверю на предмет работы по http, заработает - буду прикручивать ssl.

Comment: Вот ссылка на стэковерфлоу, по прикрутке ssl:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147714/qt-openssl-android

Comment: Я думаю что врядли на использование интернета разрешение запрашивается в рантайме, файла манифеста нет у вас? В ран тайме у андроид запрашивается доступ к контактам, к геолокации, к хранилищу и прочему.

Comment: McDaggen, манифест есть
    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё оказалось банально. В android 7+ нет поддержки ssl "из коробки" (google убрал). Обычный http заработал без проблем

Comment: Добавлю для тех, кому понадобится подцеплять ssl:
нужно добавить в проект библиотеки libcrypto.so и libssl.so. Собирал в основном по этой инструкции: https://habr.com/company/intel/blog/271013/ (в конце). Единственное, вместо APP_ABI := x86 написал abi для своего телефона. Список всех abi вот здесь:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk

Comment: ABI:=all лучше не указывайте, а перечислите их вручную: all при невозможности сборки какой-либо одной платформы остановит сборку.